# Stop anonymous function before reloading the partial view

Tags: jquery

I have a partial view that has content which is being updated constantly. When the partial view is being replaced with an `AJAX` call, two of those `JQuery` methods will run at the same time as it is against the same id or class. It will completely mess up the results.

To give an example

```
<div id="testDiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        testfunc();
    };

    function testfunc(){
        $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'Test/TestMethod'
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                    $("#testDiv").replaceWith(data);
                });
    }
</script>
```

Partial view that is being returned

```
<div id="testDiv">100</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            var value = $("#testDiv").text();
            var num = parseInt(value);
            var newNum = num + 1;
            $("#testDiv").html(newNum);
        }, 1000);
    };
</script>
```

There is also a button to call call `testfunc()` which will only replace that partial view, but then both method will change the html of the div. How can i stop the first function when the partial view is refreshed.

UPDATE --

If you call the `testfunc()` after the page has been loaded, the anonymous function within the `setInterval` will be recreated and two will run at the same time. Example 30 seconds after the page load the number inside will be 130, but if you call the `testfunc()`, both counting will be shown after the partial has been replaced. I need to stop the first method completely.

Comment: Your first step is code without obvious syntax errors. And I'm afraid your explanation of the problem is not clear. Can you edit to fix those issues?

Comment: two of those JQuery methods will run at the same time as it is against the same id or class??? which methods??

Comment: You can use $( document ).ready()

Comment: Yes kranthi, it does not matter in this case if it is an id or a class and as it say in the title, it is the anonymous function, there is only one of that in the example. Also doc ready would not change anything.